# Range between join workaround

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. Table one is a fact table containing daily transactional data. The other is a dimension table which has range information from and to dates. I am joining the two tables with a `between` clause. Is there any possibility to rewrite between join to an inner join.

Table 1:

```
dt_key   prd_id 
20170401 1
20170401 2
```

Table 2:

```
frm_dt   to_dt    cost prd_id
20170325 20170330   44 1
20170331 20170401   12 1
20170329 20170430   22 2
20170331 20170401   24 2
```

query:

```
select prd_id ,cost 
from table_1 a,table_2 b
where a.prd_id=b.prd_id
and a.dt_key between frm_dt and to_dt;
```

I want some workaround to avoid between join or adding one join condition like 
dt_key/divisor = --------

It would be great if you can suggest any logic

Comment: Could you explain why don't you like beetwen operator ?

Comment: Why?  Looks like you have to do this based on your data model.  Join on prd_id, further filter the join on the between dates.  If you are storing your dates as strings, you have other problems with your data model.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should learn to use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the ancient and fragile implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: @krokodilko I have fact table which is of having 10 billion records and dimension 1 billion record . Query takes 3 hrs

Comment: @unleashed I have tried that but plan didnt change

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will keep that in the mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided, I've provided the following.  It is essentially the same query.  What is unclear of why you want to do something different.  You are joining the tables on prd_id, the primary join, but also limiting the join based on the string dates.  I don't see how you do this any different based on the information you've provided.

```
SELECT
    prd_id,
    cost
FROM
    table_1 a
    INNER JOIN table_2 b ON (
            a.prd_id = b.prd_id
        AND
            a.dt_key BETWEEN b.frm_dt AND b.to_dt
    );
```